# Make part of square transparent- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve the scanner view as given in the picture. I've used `BoxDecoration` to design square with rounded corners.

```
            Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: BarReaderSize.width,
                    height: BarReaderSize.height,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                  ),
                )
```

[image]

Can someone help ?

Comment: make a custom `Decoration` class, something like `CornerDecoration` in https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use CustomPaint with some clipping with paths.

Please find the full example [here in the DartPad.](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3549b954e820ba9e9098697814f7ea32)

The tricky part is to determine how to clip the rounded white rectangle borders. I just used custom Path for that. I created custom Rects and created a Path out of them:

```dart
final path = Path()
      ..addRect(clippingRect0)
      ..addRect(clippingRect1)
      ..addRect(clippingRect2)
      ..addRect(clippingRect3);
```

It may be not the most efficient approach, but sometimes it's faster to draw something with CustomPainter than to experiment with some already provided widgets. This way you will have always the same look no matter how the API of the material widget changes.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 800,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: BorderPainter(),
                  child: Container(
                    width: BarReaderSize.width,
                    height: BarReaderSize.height,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final width = 3.0;
    final radius = 20.0;
    final tRadius = 2 * radius;
    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      width,
      width,
      size.width - 2 * width,
      size.height - 2 * width,
    );
    final rrect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius));
    final clippingRect0 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      0,
      0,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect1 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      size.width - tRadius,
      0,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect2 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      0,
      size.height - tRadius,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect3 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      size.width - tRadius,
      size.height - tRadius,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );

    final path = Path()
      ..addRect(clippingRect0)
      ..addRect(clippingRect1)
      ..addRect(clippingRect2)
      ..addRect(clippingRect3);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawRRect(
      rrect,
      Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = width,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class BarReaderSize {
  static double width = 200;
  static double height = 200;
}
```

Comment: he already has `Container` so its a best job for `Container.decoration` (or `foregroundDecoration`) - all you need is a custom `Decoration` class - some examples here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot

Comment: @pskink it's relatively easy to convert CustomPainter to decoration. That's how the FlutterLogo is done actually

Comment: yes I know, that's why I said that `decoration` property is much concise than `CustomPaint` - I even gave you two sample decorations

Comment: I agree 100% @pskink